# Unpack and rearrange the data

Tags: r, data.table

I am learning arule, I need to convert the current data into as.matrix

I tried to take the project apart and then present 0 and 1

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(ID=c("dog","dog","dog","cat","cat","bird"),
                 place=c("F-A-C","A-B-E","H-A","A-I-C-D","B-A","D-K-H-F"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I found this method, but not the result I want

```
library(stringr)
library(plyr)
DTa <- str_split(DT$place, "-")
DTa <- ldply(DTa ,rbind)
DT <- cbind(DT$ID, DTa)

output:
DT$ID     1   2   3   4
1   dog   F   A   C   NA
2   dog   A   B   E   NA
3   dog   H   A   NA  NA
4   cat   A   I   C   D
5   cat   B   A   NA  NA
6   bird  D   K   H   F
```

I hope the result is like this

```
    DT$ID     A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I ..... K
1    dog      1  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0 ..... 0
2    cat      1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  1 ..... 0
3    bird     0  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0 ..... 1
```

In the original data, there may be A-I, or A-Z, or A-Q, not sure how many

And the ID is not sure how many will be there.

So I can't set the length through this.

```
 str_split_fixed(DT$place, "-", 11)
```

What should I do or find out what keywords I want to do?

Thank you

Comment: You can use `+(table(stack(setNames(strsplit(DT$place, "-"), DT$ID))[2:1]) > 0)`

Comment: or with `dcast` `dcast(cSplit(DT, "place", "-", 'long'), ID ~ place, function(x) as.integer(length(x) > 0))`

Comment: "dog" has three A's in various positions, why is the result a single 1?

Comment: @r2evans Yes, I hope 1 = yes, 0 = no, not the sum of the calculations

Comment: I was thinking "length" and not "sum", but that's just a detail (and another line of code, relatively trivial).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easier method would be to use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` to split into 'long' format and then do a `dcast` to reshape into 'wide' format while specifying thee `fun.aggregate` to a logical condition based on the `length`

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(data.table)
dcast(cSplit(DT, "place", "-", 'long'), 
             ID ~ place, function(x) as.integer(length(x) > 0))
```

Or as @Frank suggested

```
dcast(unique(cSplit(DT, "place", "-", 'long'))[, v := 1], ID ~ place, fill=0)
```

---

or in `tidyverse`, split the column with `separate_rows`, get the `distinct` rows, create a column of 1's and `spread` to 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DT %>%
   separate_rows(place) %>% 
   distinct(ID, place) %>%
   mutate(n = 1) %>% 
   spread(place, n, fill = 0)
```

---

Or in `base R`, this can be done by splitting the 'place' column into a `list` of `vector`s, get the `table` of the `stack`ed `list`

```
+(table(stack(setNames(strsplit(DT$place, "-"), DT$ID))[2:1]) > 0)
```

Comment: Another variant, translating the tidyverse answer back to DT/splitstackshape: `dcast(unique(cSplit(DT, "place", "-", 'long'))[, v := 1], ID ~ place, fill=0)`

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table`-only solution:

```r
dcast(DT[, unlist(lapply(.SD, strsplit, "-")), "ID"], ID ~ V1, value.var = "V1", fun.aggregate = length)
#      ID A B C D E F H I K
# 1: bird 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1
# 2:  cat 2 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
# 3:  dog 3 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0
```

This provides "length" instead of "yes/no". To take it to that level:

```r
dcast(DT[, unlist(lapply(.SD, strsplit, "-")), "ID"], ID ~ V1, value.var = "V1", fun.aggregate = length)[, lapply(.SD, min, 1), by = "ID"]
#      ID A B C D E F H I K
# 1: bird 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1
# 2:  cat 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
# 3:  dog 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0
```

I find it a little easier to see using `magrittr`'s pipe:

```r
library(magrittr)
DT[, unlist(lapply(.SD, strsplit, "-")), "ID"] %>%
  dcast(ID ~ V1, value.var = "V1", fun.aggregate = length) %>%
  .[, lapply(.SD, min, 1), by = "ID"]
```